# mvc display different table row in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio, model-view-controller

Hey i use the Entity framework with Database first.
In my Database i have for example a table **actor** with main key "ActorID", foreign Key "*agencyID*" and an Attribute "name".
Then i have a table **movie** with main key and foreign Key "ActorID" and some attributes.
I imported the Database with the Models and then i then scaffolding the Controllers and the Views. 
Unfortunately now when i try the View **Movie**"Create", it displays on the ActorID field a drop down List with the Foreign Key "*agencyID*" instead of the "name" or the primary Key "ActorID".

```
    public partial class Actor
{
    public Kino()
    {
        this.Movie= new HashSet<Movie>();
    }

    public long ActorID{ get; set; }
    public long AgencyID { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
    public partial class Movie
{
    public long MovieID{ get; set; }
    public long ActorID{ get; set; }
    public String zyx { get; set; }
}
```

Now i wonder if it is possible to change the displayed Row to the name or the primary?
(without going to the database change their position and re due everything)

```
@Html.DropDownList("ActorID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I already changed in the Model the Position of the "*agencyID*" and the "name" but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you post your models?

Comment: i added the models to the question

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening with your seemingly mismatched scaffolding, but I'm surprised that any scaffolding is working at all with as little markup as you have on your models. Your models should have attributes designating the primary and foreign key columns: Do some reading on the attributes: [Key] and [ForeignKey].

Also, you may find that scaffolding is much more effective after you make use of the additional metadata attributes: [DisplayName], [Column], [MaxLength], etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.
You simply have to modify the scaffolded controller.

```
ViewBag.ActorID = new SelectList(db.Actors.ToList(), "ActorID", "AgencyID ");
```

to

```
ViewBag.ActorID = new SelectList(db.Actors.ToList(), "ActorID", "Name");
```

now it will display the right row.